# ‘content-type’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I'm trying to make a simple post call that will send data to mailgrid so an automatic mail will be send to the chosen person. But as i'm relative new to making API calls in general there are some thing I don't understand.

These are the errors I get when i try to make the call:

> header ‘content-type’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response

And

> CORS request did not succeed

He is my function that executes the call:

```
const sendMail = () => {
        axios.post(`https://{{private_url}}/public/mail/{user_id}/{mail_id}`, {
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
            },
            data: {
                first_name: data.first_name,
                last_name: data.last_name,
                message: data.message,
                email: data.email,
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response.headers)
                close();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                console.log(error.headers)
            });;
    }
```

What am I overseeing or where am I making a mistake ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are using the headers object incorrectly. `content-type` is separate. please use like so:

```
headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*", // this will allow all CORS requests
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": 'OPTIONS,POST,GET', // this states the allowed methods
    "Content-Type": "application/json" // this shows the expected content type
},
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out! But I still get the same errors

Comment: what error are you getting? is it a CORS issue? you'll need to enable that on the server. if it's not your server then you can't do anything I'm afraid as it's a security measure

Comment: Still this error: 
`Reason: header ‘content-type’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response`

Comment: Also, I have a CORS plugin, when I activate it, my api calls works without any problems. CORS Everywhere is the plugin for FF

Comment: you need to add that header to the server code then in the response. do you own the server?

Comment: We do, but i'm not the maintainer of it. I will send this info to that person and come back if it works or not. thanks in advance

Comment: let me know, happy to help out more!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215578/discussion-between-yorbjorn-and-red-baron).

Comment: Turns out there were a couple of problems, first is indeed that the headers needed to be added in the server. The other problem is that it's not ```Content-Type": "application/json"``` that is expected but  ```Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8```. that makes the 3rd problem that my data send in an inccorect form (JSON). So in a way, was the first step to the solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

as in [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed#:~:text=The%20HTTP%20request%20which%20makes,network%20error%20of%20some%20kind.) says:

> The HTTP request which makes use of CORS failed because the HTTP connection failed at either the network or protocol level. The error is not directly related to CORS, but is a fundamental network error of some kind.
>
> In many cases, it is caused by a browser plugin (e.g. an ad blocker or
>   privacy protector) blocking the request or VPN plugin changing origin of the request.

if there is one, you can disabled it.

The server can also block uknown origins causing **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** error.